# invalid-app-credential/Token mismatch in Flutter firebase_auth

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

I've started to setup Firebase Phone authentication in Flutter based on the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios). Unfortunately, no matter how I try, I get a `FirebaseAuthException` in the `verificationFailed` callback of the `verifyPhoneNumber` method with these values:

```
code: "invalid-app-credential"
credential: null
email: null
message: "Token mismatch"
phoneNumber: null
plugin: "firebase_auth"
stackTrace: null
tenantId: null
```

I've created a simple repository to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/peternagy1332/basic_phone_auth

1. I used `flutterfire configure` to add the app to an existing Firebase project and create the IOS application there.
2. I've added `firebase_core@2.1.1` and `firebase_auth@4.1.1`
3. I've enabled the Phone sign-in method on Firebase and added +44 7123 123 456 as a test number, and the code is 000000
4. I've added the `Push notification` and `Background modes` capability with `Background fetch` and `Remote notifications` options.
5. I've added the the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` from `GoogleService-Info.plist` as an `URL Scheme`.
6. On the Apple Developer page, I've generated a new key with `Apple Push Notifications service (APNs) service` and uploaded it as an `APNs Authentication Key` to Firebase.

The [setup section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/phone-auth#setup) of the official documentation points me to [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs). This indicates that additional modifications in the Swift code might be needed, but it's really unclear. I'm a Flutter developer and not a native IOS developer, I don't think I actually need to do all that.

Comment: FYI this happens for normal email sign in as well

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this case, it seems like a general problem with this package, I asked this question on GitHub too (https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9871). Could you elaborate what did you find during the investigation please?

Comment: I'm having the same problem after I upgraded my OS to Ventura 13.0. My phone auth code hasn't been changed for almost a year.

Comment: I've also upgraded to Ventura recently. @TheunodeBruin what about you? Also a Ventura user?

Comment: Yes this started happening after upgrading to ventura

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Make sure you set FirebaseApp.configure() in AppDelegate.swift

```swift
override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure() 
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
```

2. Set the APNS token type to AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown. The actual token type will be detected from the provisioning profile in the app’s bundle.

```swift
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)
    }
```

3. Change the aps-environment value from "development" to "unknown" in your Runner.entitlements file

[image: Runner.entitlements]

Comment: I can confirm this is working! Thanks

Comment: You need to add `import Firebase` to `AppDelegate.swift`

Comment: confirming fix also relevant for React Native on iOS 16.*

Comment: incredible, it worked! thanks man, deploying to the store!

Comment: interesting but worked. :) thanks.

Comment: Just two add my two cents I had to add import FirebaseAuth package as well in the swift delegate file.

Comment: adding unknown fixed my issue. But what unknown does here and How it would affect my production environment?

Comment: The logs complain that "no valid “aps-environment” entitlement string found for application" but hey it is working :D

Answer (score 12):

In a Flutter application I was facing `firebase_auth/invalid-app-credential: Invalid token`  error. The game changer for me was adding the `APNs auth key` to Firebase. In order to do that:

1 - Go to the Apple Developer website and create an Apple Push Notifications service `(APNs) key`. Then download it.

2 - In the `Firebase > Project Settings > Cloud Messaging > Apple app configuration` upload the APNs key.

Comment: What do I do after that?

Comment: Still getting the error

Comment: After applying the steps in order, it worked in my case.

Comment: This is the suggested answer. You have to add an APN key if you have enabled Firebase cloud messaging. Otherwise, no Firebase services will work.

Comment: This worked for me.  After creating the APN on Apple Dev website (certs, ids, profiles) I uploaded to Firebase console Cloud Messaging.  I then checked on my device and it worked.  I didn't do anything else.